# Calculating distance between two obstacles from a Lidar vertical scan

Tags: algorithms, circles, tangent-line

I have a 2D Lidar scanner that is scanning vertically (see photo [Graphical Representation of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAt0R.jpg)).  The center point is the scanner.  The bottom is the floor, top is the ceiling, and the left and right sides are selves.  I am trying to figure out, from the scan data, what the width of the largest box is that I can push down this isle.  The shelves can be variable length, and items on them can stick out into the isle way.

If I look at 90 and 180 degrees I can see that their is 852mm plus 1,090mm totaling 1,942mm.  But, their is no guarantee that what is scanned at 90 and 180 degrees are the limiting points.  Because it is a circle, I know tangent is involved, but I can not rap my head around the formula.  Additionally, the floor (which in this scan from about 140 degrees to 220 degrees) should not be included in the width calculation.  I'm sure a single formula will not solve this, and that a program will need to iterate through the data.  Help with the mathematics would be appreciated.

Thank you.

[Download link to data below](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7e43j15cbgld3w/scan.csv?dl=0)

[Graphical Representation of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAt0R.jpg)
|Bearing in degrees |Distance in mm|
|------------------:|---------------:|
|0.0439|5752|
|0.3406|5752|
|0.6207|5760|
|0.9009|5752|
|1.1865|5768|
|1.4832|5792|
|1.7633|5776|
|2.0435|5776|
|2.3236|5784|
|2.6202|5800|
|2.9059|5792|
|3.186|5792|
|3.4662|5808|
|3.7628|5816|
|4.043|5816|
|4.3231|5816|
|4.6198|5816|
|4.9054|5800|
|5.1855|5808|
|5.4657|5808|
|5.7623|5808|
|6.0425|5808|
|6.3281|5816|
|6.6248|5824|
|6.9049|5824|
|7.1851|5824|
|7.4652|5808|
|7.7618|5808|
|8.042|5816|
|8.3276|5816|
|8.6243|5816|
|8.9044|5832|
|9.1846|5856|
|9.4812|5872|
|9.7614|5888|
|10.0415|5896|
|10.3271|5896|
|10.6238|5896|
|10.9039|5896|
|11.7609|5912|
|12.453|3736|
|12.7332|3696|
|13.0133|3660|
|13.5901|3676|
|15.1831|6056|
|16.1554|3740|
|17.0123|3712|
|17.309|3724|
|17.5891|3732|
|17.8748|3736|
|18.1549|3780|
|18.4515|3816|
|18.7317|3804|
|19.0118|3784|
|19.3085|3780|
|19.5886|3792|
|23.5931|3960|
|23.8733|3944|
|24.1699|3972|
|24.4501|3996|
|24.7302|3980|
|25.0104|3980|
|25.3125|4008|
|25.5927|3996|
|25.8728|3992|
|26.1694|3996|
|26.4496|4000|
|26.7297|4020|
|27.312|4052|
|30.108|4128|
|30.3882|4216|
|30.6848|4272|
|31.7175|6848|
|31.9977|6864|
|32.2778|6920|
|33.1512|6952|
|34.0741|6112|
|34.3103|7048|
|34.5905|7160|
|34.8871|7192|
|35.1672|7232|
|35.4639|7256|
|35.7495|7312|
|36.0461|7360|
|36.3263|7384|
|36.6229|7424|
|36.9031|7416|
|37.1997|7416|
|37.4799|7432|
|37.7765|7456|
|38.0621|7488|
|38.3588|7512|
|38.6389|7528|
|38.9355|7592|
|39.2322|7664|
|39.5123|7680|
|39.809|7704|
|40.0891|7736|
|40.3857|7768|
|40.6714|7808|
|40.968|7840|
|41.2482|7808|
|41.5448|7792|
|41.825|7880|
|42.1216|7960|
|42.4017|8080|
|42.6984|8144|
|42.984|8136|
|43.2806|8160|
|43.5608|8168|
|44.1376|7792|
|44.4342|7880|
|45.2966|7976|
|46.4337|1816|
|46.7303|1812|
|47.0105|1808|
|47.3071|1806|
|47.5928|1804|
|47.8894|1800|
|48.1696|1796|
|48.4662|1802|
|48.7463|1802|
|49.043|1798|
|49.3231|1798|
|49.6198|1798|
|49.9054|1814|
|50.202|1834|
|50.4822|1850|
|50.7788|1852|
|51.059|1842|
|51.9324|1840|
|52.4652|10168|
|53.042|10208|
|53.3386|9304|
|53.9209|10064|
|54.201|10264|
|54.4977|10448|
|54.7778|10536|
|55.0745|10632|
|55.3546|10736|
|55.6512|10792|
|55.9369|10848|
|56.2335|10984|
|56.5302|10920|
|58.5571|1026|
|58.9032|1022|
|59.1998|1022|
|59.48|1020|
|59.7766|1018|
|60.0623|1016|
|60.3589|1012|
|60.639|1008|
|60.9357|1006|
|61.2158|1004|
|61.5125|1002|
|61.7926|1000|
|62.0892|998|
|62.3749|994|
|62.655|990|
|62.9517|988|
|63.2318|988|
|63.5284|986|
|63.8086|984|
|64.1547|980|
|64.4348|978|
|64.7314|976|
|65.0116|974|
|65.2917|972|
|65.5884|970|
|65.874|970|
|66.4508|968|
|66.7969|922|
|67.077|914|
|67.4176|908|
|67.7142|898|
|67.9999|892|
|68.28|892|
|69.2633|1024|
|69.5599|1024|
|69.8401|1012|
|70.1202|1010|
|70.4169|1010|
|70.7025|1010|
|71.6858|1170|
|71.9165|1196|
|72.2021|1206|
|73.0591|1202|
|73.3557|1228|
|73.6359|1228|
|73.9215|1228|
|74.9652|1360|
|75.2454|1362|
|75.542|1364|
|75.7617|1368|
|76.0583|1372|
|76.3385|1372|
|76.6406|1370|
|76.9812|1366|
|77.2614|1364|
|77.5415|1366|
|77.8436|1366|
|78.1238|1360|
|78.4039|1358|
|78.7006|1356|
|78.9807|1356|
|79.2773|1354|
|79.5575|1352|
|79.8431|1352|
|80.1398|1350|
|80.4199|1350|
|80.7166|1350|
|80.9967|1346|
|81.2769|1344|
|81.5735|1344|
|81.8591|1344|
|82.1393|1344|
|82.4359|1342|
|82.7161|1342|
|83.0127|1342|
|83.2928|1342|
|83.573|1340|
|84.1553|1344|
|84.6716|1078|
|85.0122|1068|
|85.2924|1064|
|85.589|1058|
|85.8746|1056|
|86.1548|1054|
|86.4514|1050|
|86.7316|1050|
|87.0282|1050|
|87.3083|1054|
|87.5885|1056|
|87.8906|1056|
|89.0277|852|
|89.3079|852|
|89.5935|850|
|89.8901|850|
|90.1703|852|
|90.4504|852|
|90.7471|852|
|91.0272|850|
|91.3074|850|
|91.593|850|
|91.8896|850|
|92.1698|850|
|92.45|850|
|92.7466|852|
|93.0267|852|
|93.3124|852|
|93.5925|852|
|93.8892|852|
|94.1693|852|
|94.4495|854|
|94.7461|854|
|95.0262|854|
|95.3119|856|
|95.592|856|
|95.8887|856|
|96.1688|856|
|96.449|856|
|96.7456|856|
|97.0313|858|
|97.3114|858|
|97.608|860|
|97.8882|862|
|98.1683|862|
|98.4485|862|
|98.7451|862|
|99.0308|864|
|99.3109|866|
|99.6075|866|
|99.8877|862|
|100.1678|854|
|100.448|856|
|100.7446|870|
|101.0303|872|
|101.3104|862|
|101.6071|856|
|101.8872|856|
|102.1674|854|
|102.453|852|
|102.7496|854|
|103.1561|1186|
|103.4363|1174|
|103.7769|1170|
|104.0625|1164|
|104.3591|1158|
|104.6393|1160|
|104.9194|1162|
|105.2161|1166|
|105.4358|1174|
|105.7324|1178|
|106.0126|1176|
|106.2927|1178|
|106.5729|1186|
|106.875|1192|
|107.1552|1202|
|107.4353|1218|
|107.6715|1230|
|108.0121|1228|
|108.2922|1222|
|108.5889|1220|
|108.8745|1222|
|109.1547|1222|
|110.0116|1216|
|110.528|990|
|110.8081|984|
|111.1542|980|
|111.4343|972|
|111.7145|968|
|112.0111|966|
|112.2968|960|
|112.5769|962|
|112.8735|964|
|113.1537|960|
|113.4338|956|
|113.714|952|
|114.0106|956|
|114.2963|958|
|114.5764|958|
|114.873|960|
|115.1532|956|
|115.4333|948|
|115.7135|946|
|116.0156|946|
|116.2958|948|
|116.5759|952|
|116.8561|954|
|117.1527|956|
|117.4329|958|
|117.7185|962|
|117.9987|966|
|118.2788|968|
|118.5754|970|
|118.8556|974|
|119.1357|976|
|119.4214|980|
|119.6521|984|
|119.9323|988|
|120.2179|996|
|120.498|994|
|120.7782|988|
|121.0748|988|
|121.355|988|
|121.6406|988|
|122.2009|996|
|122.9041|1472|
|123.1842|1476|
|123.4644|1476|
|124.0906|1394|
|124.4366|1364|
|124.9365|1424|
|125.2332|1442|
|126.0736|1112|
|126.3593|1104|
|126.6394|1098|
|126.9196|1094|
|127.2162|1090|
|127.4963|1086|
|127.7765|1086|
|128.0621|1088|
|128.3423|1086|
|128.6389|1086|
|128.9191|1086|
|129.1992|1086|
|129.4794|1086|
|129.765|1088|
|130.0616|1090|
|130.3418|1094|
|130.6219|1094|
|130.9021|1098|
|131.1823|1104|
|131.4679|1108|
|131.7645|1116|
|131.9843|1120|
|132.2644|1122|
|132.561|1130|
|132.8412|1138|
|133.1213|1140|
|133.4015|1146|
|133.6871|1154|
|133.9838|1160|
|134.2639|1168|
|134.4836|1178|
|134.7803|1174|
|135.0604|1180|
|135.3406|1198|
|135.6207|1192|
|135.9009|1180|
|136.1865|1178|
|136.4832|1180|
|136.7633|1174|
|137.1094|1164|
|137.3895|1156|
|137.6697|1160|
|137.9498|1168|
|138.23|1168|
|138.5266|1168|
|138.8123|1170|
|139.0265|1178|
|141.2018|1366|
|141.4819|1362|
|141.7621|1348|
|142.0422|1344|
|142.3279|1342|
|142.6245|1338|
|142.9047|1330|
|143.1848|1324|
|143.465|1320|
|143.7451|1316|
|144.0417|1312|
|144.3274|1308|
|144.6075|1304|
|144.8877|1298|
|145.2338|1294|
|145.5139|1292|
|145.7941|1288|
|146.0742|1284|
|146.3708|1280|
|146.651|1274|
|146.9366|1268|
|147.2168|1268|
|147.4969|1264|
|147.7936|1262|
|148.0737|1258|
|148.3594|1252|
|148.6395|1248|
|148.9197|1246|
|149.2163|1244|
|149.4965|1240|
|149.7766|1236|
|150.0623|1232|
|150.4028|1228|
|150.683|1224|
|150.9686|1220|
|151.2488|1218|
|151.5454|1216|
|151.8256|1214|
|152.1057|1210|
|152.3859|1208|
|152.6715|1204|
|152.9681|1202|
|153.2483|1200|
|153.5284|1198|
|153.8086|1194|
|154.0887|1190|
|154.3744|1188|
|154.671|1186|
|154.9512|1184|
|155.2313|1182|
|155.5115|1178|
|155.7916|1176|
|156.0938|1174|
|156.3739|1172|
|156.7145|1168|
|156.9946|1168|
|157.2803|1166|
|157.5604|1162|
|157.8406|1160|
|158.1207|1158|
|158.4174|1156|
|158.703|1154|
|158.9832|1154|
|159.2633|1150|
|159.5435|1148|
|159.8401|1146|
|160.1202|1144|
|160.4059|1142|
|160.686|1142|
|160.9662|1140|
|161.2628|1138|
|161.543|1136|
|161.8231|1136|
|162.1088|1134|
|162.3889|1130|
|162.6691|1128|
|162.9657|1128|
|163.2458|1126|
|163.526|1124|
|163.8116|1124|
|164.0918|1122|
|164.3884|1120|
|164.6686|1118|
|164.9487|1118|
|165.2948|1116|
|165.575|1114|
|165.8551|1114|
|166.1353|1112|
|166.4374|1112|
|166.7175|1112|
|166.9977|1110|
|167.2778|1108|
|167.558|1108|
|167.8436|1106|
|168.1403|1104|
|168.4204|1104|
|168.7006|1104|
|168.9807|1104|
|169.2609|1102|
|169.5575|1100|
|169.8431|1100|
|170.1233|1100|
|170.4034|1100|
|170.6836|1098|
|170.9802|1098|
|171.2604|1098|
|171.546|1096|
|171.8262|1096|
|172.1063|1096|
|172.3865|1094|
|172.6831|1094|
|172.9688|1094|
|173.2489|1092|
|173.5291|1092|
|173.8092|1092|
|174.1058|1092|
|174.386|1090|
|174.6716|1090|
|174.9518|1092|
|175.2319|1090|
|175.5286|1090|
|175.8087|1090|
|176.0889|1090|
|176.3745|1090|
|176.6547|1090|
|176.9348|1090|
|177.2314|1090|
|177.5116|1090|
|177.7917|1090|
|178.0774|1090|
|178.3575|1090|
|178.6542|1090|
|178.9343|1090|
|179.2145|1090|
|179.4946|1090|
|179.7803|1090|
|180.0769|1090|
|180.3571|1090|
|180.6372|1090|
|180.9174|1090|
|181.203|1092|
|181.4832|1092|
|181.7798|1092|
|182.0599|1092|
|182.3401|1092|
|182.6202|1092|
|182.9059|1096|
|183.2025|1096|
|183.4827|1096|
|183.7628|1096|
|184.043|1098|
|184.3231|1098|
|184.6198|1098|
|184.9054|1100|
|185.1855|1100|
|185.4657|1100|
|185.7458|1100|
|186.026|1102|
|186.3281|1102|
|186.6083|1102|
|186.8884|1102|
|187.1686|1104|
|187.4487|1106|
|187.7454|1108|
|188.031|1108|
|188.3112|1108|
|188.5913|1110|
|188.8715|1110|
|189.1681|1112|
|189.4482|1112|
|189.7339|1112|
|190.014|1114|
|190.2942|1116|
|190.5304|1118|
|190.8105|1120|
|191.0907|1120|
|191.3708|1122|
|191.6675|1124|
|191.9531|1124|
|192.2333|1126|
|192.5134|1128|
|192.7936|1128|
|193.0902|1130|
|193.3704|1132|
|193.656|1134|
|193.9362|1136|
|194.2163|1138|
|194.4965|1138|
|194.7931|1140|
|195.0732|1142|
|195.3589|1142|
|195.639|1144|
|195.9192|1146|
|196.2158|1148|
|196.496|1152|
|196.7761|1154|
|197.0618|1154|
|197.3419|1156|
|197.6385|1158|
|197.9187|1162|
|198.1989|1164|
|198.479|1164|
|198.7811|1166|
|199.0613|1170|
|199.292|1172|
|199.5776|1174|
|199.8578|1178|
|200.1379|1180|
|200.4346|1182|
|200.7147|1184|
|200.9949|1188|
|201.2915|1192|
|201.5771|1194|
|201.8573|1196|
|202.1375|1196|
|202.4341|1198|
|202.7142|1204|
|202.9999|1208|
|203.28|1210|
|203.5767|1212|
|203.8568|1214|
|204.137|1216|
|204.4336|1220|
|204.7137|1224|
|204.9994|1228|
|205.2301|1230|
|205.5103|1232|
|205.7959|1236|
|206.0925|1238|
|206.3727|1244|
|206.6528|1246|
|206.9495|1250|
|207.2296|1252|
|207.5153|1256|
|207.7954|1262|
|208.092|1264|
|208.3722|1268|
|208.6523|1272|
|208.949|1276|
|209.2291|1278|
|209.5148|1282|
|209.7949|1286|
|210.0916|1292|
|210.3113|1296|
|210.6079|1298|
|210.8881|1304|
|211.1682|1310|
|211.4484|1316|
|211.745|1318|
|212.0306|1320|
|212.3108|1324|
|212.6074|1332|
|212.8876|1338|
|213.1677|1342|
|213.4479|1348|
|213.75|1350|
|214.0302|1354|
|214.3103|1358|
|214.5465|1368|
|214.8267|1374|
|215.1233|1376|
|215.4034|1380|
|215.6836|1384|
|215.9637|1392|
|216.2604|1398|
|216.546|1404|
|216.8262|1410|
|217.1228|1414|
|217.403|1420|
|217.6831|1426|
|217.9688|1436|
|218.2654|1442|
|218.5455|1444|
|218.7762|1448|
|219.0619|1456|
|219.342|1468|
|219.6222|1490|
|219.9188|1494|
|220.4791|1474|
|220.7813|1460|
|221.0614|1454|
|221.792|1290|
|222.0776|1280|
|222.3743|1278|
|222.6544|1272|
|222.9346|1270|
|223.2312|1276|
|223.5114|1278|
|223.7915|1258|
|224.3738|1282|
|224.6539|1270|
|224.9341|1264|
|225.2307|1258|
|225.5109|1250|
|225.7965|1242|
|226.0931|1238|
|226.3733|1232|
|226.7139|1222|
|226.9995|1216|
|227.2961|1214|
|227.5763|1210|
|227.8729|1204|
|228.1531|1196|
|228.4332|1190|
|228.7299|1184|
|229.0155|1180|
|229.3121|1178|
|229.6527|1170|
|229.9329|1164|
|230.2185|1160|
|230.5151|1156|
|230.7953|1150|
|231.0754|1144|
|231.3721|1138|
|231.6522|1136|
|231.9489|1130|
|232.229|1126|
|232.5146|1122|
|232.8113|1118|
|233.1519|1112|
|233.4375|1110|
|233.7177|1106|
|234.0143|1102|
|234.2944|1098|
|234.5911|1094|
|234.8712|1090|
|235.1514|1096|
|235.448|1102|
|235.7336|1110|
|235.9644|1118|
|236.25|1126|
|236.5466|1136|
|236.8268|1144|
|237.1234|1152|
|237.4036|1142|
|237.6837|1122|
|238.0298|1112|
|238.3264|1110|
|238.6066|1108|
|238.8867|1098|
|239.1833|1098|
|239.9799|1118|
|241.2488|1052|
|241.5289|1046|
|241.8256|1042|
|242.1057|1038|
|242.4023|1036|
|242.6825|1034|
|242.9681|1030|
|243.2648|1028|
|243.5449|1028|
|243.8416|1028|
|244.1217|1026|
|244.4678|1024|
|244.6985|1026|
|244.9841|1026|
|245.2643|1028|
|245.5609|1032|
|245.8411|1034|
|246.1377|1034|
|246.4178|1034|
|246.698|1038|
|246.9946|1042|
|247.2803|1046|
|247.5769|1050|
|247.8571|1054|
|248.1372|1060|
|248.4338|1062|
|248.714|1066|
|249.527|1074|
|249.9994|1554|
|250.2795|1546|
|250.5597|1548|
|250.8563|1548|
|251.1365|1544|
|251.4331|1540|
|251.7792|1536|
|252.0593|1532|
|252.6361|1532|
|253.3722|988|
|253.6523|986|
|253.9325|986|
|254.2291|988|
|254.5587|982|
|254.8553|980|
|255.0751|996|
|255.3717|1004|
|255.6519|994|
|255.9375|990|
|256.2341|988|
|256.5143|986|
|256.7944|986|
|257.0746|986|
|257.3712|986|
|257.6514|986|
|257.937|984|
|258.2336|984|
|258.5138|984|
|258.7939|984|
|259.0741|984|
|259.3707|984|
|259.9365|984|
|261.7767|1470|
|262.0624|1468|
|262.3425|1470|
|262.6392|1468|
|262.9193|1468|
|263.1995|1468|
|263.4961|1468|
|263.7762|1466|
|264.0619|1466|
|264.342|1466|
|264.6387|1466|
|264.9188|1468|
|265.199|1468|
|265.4791|1466|
|265.7813|1474|
|266.8579|954|
|267.1381|952|
|267.4182|952|
|267.6984|954|
|267.995|950|
|268.2806|954|
|268.5608|970|
|268.8574|974|
|269.1376|966|
|269.4177|964|
|269.6979|962|
|270|962|
|270.2802|964|
|270.5603|964|
|270.8405|966|
|271.1371|968|
|271.4172|970|
|271.7029|970|
|271.9995|970|
|272.2797|970|
|272.5598|972|
|272.84|972|
|273.1366|974|
|273.4167|974|
|273.7024|976|
|273.999|976|
|274.2792|978|
|274.5593|978|
|274.8395|980|
|275.1361|982|
|275.3558|984|
|275.6525|984|
|275.9326|984|
|276.2183|986|
|277.2015|1482|
|277.4817|1482|
|277.7783|1484|
|278.3386|1484|
|279.0308|1316|
|279.3109|1302|
|279.6515|1286|
|280.2777|1224|
|280.5579|1222|
|280.8545|1224|
|281.1401|1228|
|281.4203|1228|
|281.651|1232|
|281.9366|1236|
|282.2168|1240|
|282.5134|1240|
|282.7936|1242|
|283.0737|1244|
|283.3704|1248|
|283.656|1250|
|283.9362|1250|
|284.2163|1252|
|284.5129|1254|
|284.7931|1256|
|285.0732|1264|
|285.3589|1276|
|285.6555|1280|
|285.9357|1286|
|286.2158|1290|
|286.5125|1292|
|286.7926|1292|
|287.0728|1292|
|287.3584|1294|
|287.5891|1300|
|287.8748|1310|
|288.7317|1312|
|289.8248|1404|
|290.105|1390|
|290.3906|1370|
|290.7312|1354|
|291.0114|1354|
|291.308|1346|
|291.5936|1338|
|291.8738|1340|
|292.1539|1324|
|292.4506|1308|
|292.7307|1310|
|293.0109|1300|
|293.3569|1280|
|293.6371|1280|
|293.9337|1288|
|294.2139|1292|
|294.7797|1294|
|295.0104|1356|
|295.2466|1372|
|295.5267|1376|
|295.8124|1384|
|296.109|1388|
|296.3892|1394|
|297.2461|1410|
|298.125|10984|
|298.4052|10888|
|298.6853|10984|
|298.9655|10984|
|299.5422|9784|
|299.8279|9784|
|300.4047|10336|
|300.6848|10376|
|300.965|10376|
|301.5417|9736|
|301.8274|9792|
|302.1075|9968|
|302.4042|10040|
|302.6843|9936|
|302.9645|9808|
|303.2446|9712|
|303.5468|9632|
|303.8269|9592|
|304.1071|9584|
|304.3872|9584|
|304.6838|9552|
|304.964|9472|
|305.2496|9408|
|305.5463|9384|
|305.8264|9336|
|306.1066|9280|
|306.6833|9200|
|307.2491|8304|
|307.5458|8480|
|307.8259|8608|
|308.1061|8696|
|308.3862|8728|
|308.6829|8720|
|308.9685|8712|
|309.2487|8664|
|309.5288|8584|
|309.8254|8520|
|310.1056|8464|
|310.3857|8408|
|310.6714|8368|
|310.968|8368|
|311.2482|8296|
|311.5887|8152|
|311.8744|8112|
|312.1545|8120|
|312.4512|8104|
|312.7313|8096|
|313.0115|8064|
|313.2916|7984|
|313.5938|7920|
|313.8739|7912|
|314.1541|7864|
|314.4507|7808|
|314.7308|7776|
|315.011|7680|
|315.2966|7640|
|315.5933|7624|
|315.8734|7632|
|316.1536|7632|
|316.4337|7584|
|316.7303|7552|
|317.0105|7512|
|317.8729|7472|
|318.1531|6456|
|318.7299|6376|
|319.2957|7168|
|319.5758|7192|
|319.8724|7168|
|320.1526|7160|
|320.4327|7160|
|320.7294|7056|
|321.015|6896|
|321.2952|6904|
|321.5753|6976|
|321.8719|6976|
|322.1521|6960|
|322.4323|6912|
|322.7179|6888|
|323.0145|6904|
|323.2947|6912|
|323.5748|6912|
|323.8715|6912|
|324.1516|6872|
|324.4373|6856|
|324.7174|6816|
|325.014|6792|
|325.2942|6800|
|325.5743|6768|
|325.8545|6760|
|326.1511|6768|
|326.4368|6744|
|326.7169|6696|
|326.9971|6680|
|327.2937|6664|
|328.1561|6160|
|328.4802|6128|
|328.7769|6120|
|328.9966|6216|
|329.2932|6208|
|329.6228|6040|
|329.9194|5904|
|330.1996|5848|
|330.4797|5816|
|330.7764|5784|
|331.062|5872|
|331.5729|6304|
|331.8585|6352|
|332.1387|6352|
|332.4353|6336|
|332.7155|6328|
|332.9956|6312|
|333.2813|6232|
|333.9185|5456|
|334.1986|5376|
|334.4843|5352|
|335.061|5408|
|335.6213|6072|
|335.8575|6168|
|336.1377|6184|
|336.4343|6152|
|336.7639|6104|
|337.0605|6064|
|337.3407|6048|
|337.6208|6048|
|337.9175|6056|
|338.2031|6048|
|338.4833|6040|
|338.7634|6048|
|339.0601|6024|
|339.3402|6032|
|339.6204|6056|
|339.906|6048|
|340.2026|6032|
|340.4828|6000|
|340.7629|5984|
|341.0596|5976|
|341.3397|5952|
|341.6199|5960|
|341.9055|5944|
|342.2021|5928|
|342.4823|5928|
|342.7625|5912|
|343.0591|5904|
|343.3392|5896|
|343.6249|5888|
|343.905|5864|
|344.2017|5864|
|344.4818|5864|
|344.762|5856|
|345.0586|5856|
|345.3387|5848|
|345.6244|5840|
|345.9045|5848|
|346.2012|5848|
|346.4813|5848|
|346.7615|5856|
|347.0581|5848|
|347.3438|5856|
|347.6239|5848|
|347.9041|5840|
|348.2007|5832|
|348.4808|5840|
|348.761|5840|
|349.0466|5832|
|349.3433|5816|
|349.6234|5816|
|349.9036|5808|
|350.2002|5800|
|350.4803|5808|
|350.7605|5792|
|351.0461|5776|
|351.3428|5784|
|351.6229|5768|
|351.9031|5760|
|352.0624|5768|
|352.3425|5768|
|352.6392|5744|
|352.9193|5752|
|353.1995|5752|
|353.4796|5760|
|353.7762|5776|
|354.6222|5032|
|354.9188|5000|
|355.4791|4960|
|356.0614|5648|
|356.3416|5752|
|356.6217|5784|
|356.9183|5792|
|357.1985|5784|
|357.4841|5760|
|357.7643|5768|
|358.0609|5784|
|358.3411|5752|
|358.6212|5736|
|358.9014|5752|
|359.198|5768|
|359.4836|5760|
|359.7638|5760|

Comment: what mean the green points?

Comment: Do you mean the image?  It has blue dots which represents the closes object to the scanner at a given bearing from the scanner.  I do not see green in the image.

Comment: Do you have  a real picture of the scene?

Comment: This is a representation of the area.  https://www.wokandskillet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/sunrise-asian-market-sauces-720x540.jpg.webp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follows a MATHEMATICA script easily understood by itself.

```
data = Import["/home/test/Downloads/scan.csv", "Data"];
data0 = Take[data, {2, Length[data]}];

ceiling = 2000;
floor = -1000;
near = {};
For[k = 1, k <= Length[data0], k++, 
 If[data0[[k, 2]] < ceiling, 
   r = data0[[k, 2]]; 
   a = Pi data0[[k, 1]]/180 + Pi/2; 
   AppendTo[near, {r Cos[a], r Sin[a]}]
 ]
]

gr0 = ListPlot[near, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}];

near2 = {};
For[k = 1, k <= Length[near], k++, 
 If[near[[k, 2]] > floor, AppendTo[near2, near[[k]]]]
]

leftmax = -20000;
rightmin = 20000;
For[k = 1, k <= Length[near2], k++, 
 If[near2[[k, 1]] < 0 && near2[[k, 1]] > leftmax, 
   leftmax = near2[[k, 1]]
 ]
]

For[k = 1, k <= Length[near2], k++, 
 If[near2[[k, 1]] > 0 && near2[[k, 1]] < rightmin, 
 rightmin = near2[[k, 1]]
 ]
]

safe = {{leftmax, ceiling}, {leftmax, floor}, {rightmin, floor},{rightmin, ceiling}, {leftmax, ceiling}};
gr2 = ListLinePlot[safe, PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False];
Show[gr0, gr2, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I can code in a few languages, but I do not know MATHEMATICA (but I will learn enough of it to understand this code).   Would you be able to give me a little help on what the first FOR loop is accomplishing?   I get the idea of what the remainder of the code is calculating.  Switching it to C++ or Node will be a fun process.

Comment: The first `For` selects the points at a lower distance from the emitting center (`ceiling`) and makes the transformation from polar to cartesian to the selected points.